# How to implement Session Timeout in Java?

Tags: java, session, session-timeout

We have a simple Java based application. There, we create session on receiving createSession() request from the client. Then we execute "operations" on the session and finally on receiving release(), we destroy the session object. Now I want to implement session timeout feature for the application. If the session is idle for a configurable amount of time, destroy it. I can create a dedicated thread which will wake up after certain interval of time and iterate through all the session objects. Based on the "lastAccessedTimeStamp" on each object, it would invoke release() whenever applicable. What else can be done? What are the other APIs that could be used here?

Comment: Can you give us more precisions on your application context ? Does it ruun in application server (JavaEE) or standalone (JavaSE) ?

Comment: This is a web server (apache-tomcat + apache-cxf). But, the sessions which we are creating are the custom sessions (POJO). So, the lifetime of those POJOs can't be controlled through the session timeout parameter in the web.xml

Answer (score 2):

What kind of application is this? For web applications, session handling (including timeout) is done automatically by the servlet container; the timeout value is set in the `web.xml` configuration file.

If you want to reinvent all these wheels then yes, a separate thread that periodically (perhaps once per minute) checks all sessions and releases the timed-out ones sounds like a sensible implementation.

Comment: The same comment applies here: This is a web server (apache-tomcat + apache-cxf). But, the sessions which we are creating are the custom sessions (POJO). So, the lifetime of those POJOs can't be controlled through the session timeout parameter in the web.xml. Any suggestion for the APIs those can be used?

Comment: @Arnab Biswas: Sure. The servlet API. There you get a mature, well-supported implementation of sessions. If for some reason you insist on reinventing the wheel, you're on your own - but that's what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we can't use the session handling mechanism defined in Servlet API. My question is if my sessions are basicay POJO, ehat mechanism can be used for implementing timeout? Anything from java.util.concurrent package?

Comment: @ArnabBiswas There is something I definitely don't understand here. How is it possible for you to use the very http infrastructure provided by Tomcat without thinking first about using its session mechanism ? [This paragraph (on MVC and CXF)](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-ModelViewControllersupport) suggests that CXF can share ssession info with styandard web mechanism, and can as a consequence been seen as compatible. So why on earth should you reinvent your own ? I urge you to dive deep in CXF doc to see how you could use standard web sessions with your CXF application

Comment: @riduidel The web service we are using is the client of another application. So within our service we need to use the API exposed by that particular application. The POJO I have mentioned here, is nothing but an API object provided by that particular API framework. The session here is more of a business logic than a framework feature.